# "If" function (js). Syntactic advice required for beginner

Tags: javascript

This is a part of a googlescript i am creating. Please have a look, in the if condition if I have to check for a variable having any of the 2 given values (1 or 0) then is the correct way?

`if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress != '' && daysleft == 1 && daysleft == 0) { //`

Prevents sending sending same mail again to a person, also skips blank cells

> //if daysleft =1 or 0 then send mail .

Comment: you could probably get away with daysleft <= 1?

Comment: this `daysleft == 1 && daysleft == 0` will never evaluate to true. Do you realize why?

Comment: Well based on your code `if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress != '' && daysleft == 1 && daysleft == 0)` - There's no way that `daysleft` can be `0` AND `1` at the same time is there...

Answer (score 1):

You could group the logical OR `||` condition of `daysleft`, because of the higher operator precedence of logical AND`&&`. `daysleft` can have either zero or one as value.

For `emailAddress`, you could just use the value, and if it is an empty string, it is a falsy value, otherwise a truthy value, which resilves to `true`.

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress && (daysleft == 1 || daysleft == 0)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions, daysleft == 1 && daysleft == 0 which are contradictory, either:

- daysLeft is not 1 or 0 - False && False => False
- daysLeft is 1          - True  && False => False
- daysLeft is 0          - False && True  => False

So the output will always be false

Answer (score 0):

Using `&&` in the condition you wrote will require `daysleft` to equal both `1` and `0`, which is impossible.

```
if ( ... && daysleft == 1 && daysleft == 0) {
```

*To fix this you will have to put an `OR` between them.*

As for the syntax, I would write it like this for this specific case:

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress && daysleft < 2)
```

For other cases with `ORing` i would separate the condition in a variable, and use it inside with an `and` as follows:

```
const lessThanTwoDaysLeft = daysleft === 1 || daysleft === 0;
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress && lessThanTwoDaysLeft)
```

If you want to inline the cases, you would have to write it like this:

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress && (daysleft === 0 || daysleft === 1))
```

The parenthesis will group them so the result of the `(daysleft === 0 || daysleft === 1)` will be used for the overall condition.

Finally, I do recommend that you use triple equals, instead of two.

Comment: Thank you to Nina Scholz, jrtapsell and Ahmad Bamieh that was indeed helpful and really quick, and really good logical explanation for a noobie like me. Much appreciated!